# Resize a set of IMGs to fit a container DIV

Tags: html, css, image

I have a set of N images (square but hopefully that's not important) that I want to fit inside a container div and I want to resize the image elements so that they consume the maximum amount of space within the div.

I have found lots of examples for a single image or even, a single line of images but nothing for a 2 dimensional grid.

My current approach is to calculate the image size myself in JS and then use that directly but taking account of all the margins, padding etc. is proving difficult.

What CSS feature should I be using?

Example code (with hard coded IMG width/height) - here it looks like the best fit is 4x2 but each IMG needs to be bigger so that the full width/height is utilized:

```css
img {
  border: 1px orange dotted;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 64px;
  top: 32px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #99f;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://vectorflags.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/flags/hk-square-01.png">
  <img src="https://vectorflags.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/flags/cr-square-01.png">
  <img src="https://vectorflags.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/flags/uk-square-01.png">
  <img src="https://vectorflags.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/flags/fr-square-01.png">
  <img src="https://vectorflags.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/flags/cz-square-01.png">
  <img src="https://vectorflags.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/flags/se-square-01.png">
  <img src="https://vectorflags.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/flags/au-square-01.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize flexbox for this layout. Using `flex-grow: 1` will make sure that the full container size is used. Setting a fixed width for the images defines the smallest size. By using `flex-flow: row wrap` the images wrap accordingly into the next row.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #99f;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px orange dotted;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
        <img
          src="https://vectorflags.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/flags/hk-square-01.png"
        />
        <img
          src="https://vectorflags.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/flags/cr-square-01.png"
        />
        <img
          src="https://vectorflags.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/flags/uk-square-01.png"
        />
        <img
          src="https://vectorflags.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/flags/fr-square-01.png"
        />
        <img
          src="https://vectorflags.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/flags/cz-square-01.png"
        />
        <img
          src="https://vectorflags.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/flags/se-square-01.png"
        />
        <img
          src="https://vectorflags.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/flags/au-square-01.png"
        />
      </div>
```

Comment: Your solution should be here. Copy the snippet down to your answer and make changes. Also, [never link "here"](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/links-should-never-say-click-here/#here-conceals-what-users-are-clicking).

Comment: Thank you so much.  This seems really close but I am not understanding one piece.  I would like to specify the width/height of the container DIV and if I do that with your example, the images are stretched.  The container is tall and narrow in my application. I observe that if I do not specify a height - just width, it looks correct but then the images do not fill the vertical height (as much as they can).  I am sorry I am not explaining it well - English is not my first language.

Comment: Wondering if explaining how I do it (badly) in my code would help me explain.  I have a tall narrow div and N images - anywhere from 6 to 50.  I start X & Y at 0 and iterate over the images, adding a counter for SIZE to X.  When X exceeds the DIV width, I reset X and add SIZE to Y.  When I get to the end of the images, if Y has exceeded the height of the DIV, I try again with a smaller value for SIZE.  I keep doing this until I don't exceed Y and use the resulting value of SIZE as the IMG width/height attributes when I add the images to the DIV.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand completely, what you are trying to achieve. You could set a max-width or even a defined width on the images in order to prevent stretching. But in that case, as you said, the images would not fill the container width. So either you define the container width, or you define the image-width. Defining both will interfere with the look of the layout. I think your second explanation of calculating the height and width of the elements is a bit excessive. You should be able to achieve this with just css. Maybe you could help me understand how it should look in the end.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry  My app has an area (non-square) for selection based on a thumbnail.   Each thumbnail is square .  Depending on context, there are between 4 and 30 thumbnails in the same area.  I want each thumbnail to be as large as possible.   The example that isherwood was kind enough to share works in that it fits the images to the div but it doesn't maximise each image size.  It fits with (say) 4 on a line then 3 on the next line but that leaves space underneath.  The final layout should perhaps be 3 rows of 2 larger images and 1 row of a single larger image or even 7 rows of 1 image.

Comment: Ok I think I got what you would like to achieve now. I updated my answer. Please check again.

Comment: Oh gosh thank you  - I never get the "post updated emails" from this site so I check back regularly but I still missed your last comment - I' sorry. Trying now.  I came back to post my JS version - be interesting to compare.. https://jsfiddle.net/ov190d8k/4/